# Django filtering a model query with filter method

Tags: python, django

Why does this code:

```
products_model = Product.objects.filter(sub_category__name__iexact=sub)
supplier_filter = SupplierFilter(request.GET, queryset=products_model)
products = supplier_filter.qs
```

Give me this error:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'BYGGMAX'.
```

Ive had trouble with this alot now. Can someone explain whats goin on. When i use the filter method its more complicated to filter the model, how so? Really interested in learning more on how this works.

Comment: Can you provide the model details?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what is inside `request.GET`, but it seems that it has a key `id` with value `'BYGGMAX'`. So when you are accessing `supplier_filter.qs`, it is trying to add a filter with `id='BYGGMAX'`. But as the `id` field is an int data type, so it raised this error. What you can do is ensure that `id` has a proper value in `request.GET` or don't pass `id` in `request.GET` according to your need.

You can go through the codebase to understand more.
https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/56eaae15e4fab97483e1353080a0c320f18c1014/django_filters/filterset.py#L237